# @PostConstruct is loading beans using Hiberante, but JSF is not showing them in dataTable?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, datatable, postconstruct

So @PostConstruct init function is working correctly, I've tested it with System.println() but JSF is still not showing any information. Any suggestions how to fix this or how to do it the other way?

**EventBean**

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    events = dataAccess.loadEvents();
}
```

**EventDAO** - *Data Access Object*

```
public List<EventBean> loadEvents()
{
    System.err.println("LOADING EVENTS BEGINING OF SESSION");

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

        System.err.println("LOADING EVENTS IN SESSION");

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Dogadjaj.class);

        List<Dogadjaj> dList = (List<Dogadjaj>) criteria.list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    List<EventBean> beans = new ArrayList<EventBean>();
    EventBean bean = new EventBean();

    System.err.println("LOADING EVENTS OUT OF SESSION");

    for(Dogadjaj entity : dList)
    {
        bean.setName(entity.getIme());
        bean.setOffice(entity.getBlagajna().getIme());
        bean.setDate(entity.getVreme().toString());
    }

    System.err.println("SAMPLE BEAN :" + bean.getName());

    return beans;
}
```

**System.out**

```
Severe:   LOADING EVENTS IN SESSION
Info:   Hibernate: select this_.EVENT_ID as EVENT_ID1_3_1_, this_.blagajna_OFFICE_ID as blagajna4_3_1_, this_.ime as ime2_3_1_, this_.vreme as vreme3_3_1_, blagajna2_.OFFICE_ID as OFFICE_I1_1_0_, blagajna2_.adresa as adresa2_1_0_, blagajna2_.email as email3_1_0_, blagajna2_.ime as ime4_1_0_, blagajna2_.telefon as telefon5_1_0_ from Dogadjaj this_ left outer join Blagajna blagajna2_ on this_.blagajna_OFFICE_ID=blagajna2_.OFFICE_ID
Severe:   LOADING EVENTS OUT OF SESSION
Severe:   SAMPLE BEAN :Mitar Miri?
```

**JSF** *- dataTable*

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
    <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
    <h:dataTable id="events" value="#{event.events}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Office"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.office}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Date"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.date}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets the `beans` of EventDAO in request scope?

Comment: Actually I've just came here to delete this post. Everything is fine, except when I was copying from Hibernate dList to beans list, in for cause, never added it to the list with `beans.add(bean)` ... I'm ashamed of this post. Hours of debugging have done it's purpose.

Thank you very much!

Comment: ok cool, all the best :)